# How is it possible to overwrite a dll file in web root folder while IIS is running the app?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I want to overwrite a file in the web root directory of an ASP.NET Core application running on IIS. I copy the file remotely but it say that the file is under the use and cannot overwrite. How can I copy dll files remotely while ISS is running?

Comment: .NET 6 introduced that https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2021/07/19/aspnetcore6-shaddow-copy-iis.html

Comment: ASP.NET core application is different from asp.net. ASP.NET core should stop running to replace dll file. Unless you use asp.net application or .NET 6.

Answer (score 0):

If the App within IIS can be set offline briefly, you can use `app_offline.htm`

> The App Offline file (app_offline.htm) is used by the ASP.NET Core Module to shut down an app.
>
> If a file with the name app_offline.htm is detected in the root directory of an app, the ASP.NET Core Module attempts to gracefully shut down the app and stop processing incoming requests. If the app is still running after the number of seconds defined in shutdownTimeLimit, the ASP.NET Core Module stops the running process.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline?view=aspnetcore-6.0

If the app needs to keep running the solution with [Shadow Copies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/shadow-copy-assemblies) mentioned by Lex Li in the comments might be helpful.

**Note:** Shadow Copys are still experimental in .net 6. At the moment this feature still is experimental as far as I know. this discussion might be helpful:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/23733